# Is there a C# API to regenerate Shared Access Keys for an Azure Service Bus Namespace?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I've found APIs to regenerate keys for queues and topics, like:

```
TopicDescription topicDescription = namespaceManager.GetTopic(topicName);

SharedAccessAuthorizationRule rule;

bool topicSuccess = topicDescription.Authorization.TryGetSharedAccessAuthorizationRule("RootManageSharedAccessKey", out rule);

if (topicSuccess)
{
    string newkey = SharedAccessAuthorizationRule.GenerateRandomKey();
    rule.PrimaryKey = newkey;
    namespaceManager.UpdateTopic(topicDescription);
}
```

[The docs online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#configuration-for-shared-access-signature-authentication) claim that "you can configure the `SharedAccessAuthorizationRule` rule on the Service Bus namespaces, queues, or topics", however I can only find the C# API for queues and topics.  I found a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces/regeneratekeys) for the namespace level, but nothing else.

Is there a supported way to regenerate the namespace-level keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can regenerate the namespace key using [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent/) library.

There is a method `RegenerateKeysAsync` available in this library to regenerate the access keys of the namespace.

All the namespace level operations can be done using this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code repo for examples

[Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/SDKs/ServiceBus/Management.ServiceBus/Generated/NamespacesOperations.cs)

below code you would be interested in

```js
 public async Task<AzureOperationResponse<AccessKeys>> RegenerateKeysWithHttpMessagesAsync(string resourceGroupName, string namespaceName, string authorizationRuleName, RegenerateAccessKeyParameters parameters, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (resourceGroupName == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "resourceGroupName");
            }
            if (resourceGroupName != null)
            {
                if (resourceGroupName.Length > 90)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MaxLength, "resourceGroupName", 90);
                }
                if (resourceGroupName.Length < 1)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MinLength, "resourceGroupName", 1);
                }
            }
            if (namespaceName == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "namespaceName");
            }
            if (namespaceName != null)
            {
                if (namespaceName.Length > 50)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MaxLength, "namespaceName", 50);
                }
                if (namespaceName.Length < 6)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MinLength, "namespaceName", 6);
                }
            }
            if (authorizationRuleName == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "authorizationRuleName");
            }
            if (authorizationRuleName != null)
            {
                if (authorizationRuleName.Length > 50)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MaxLength, "authorizationRuleName", 50);
                }
                if (authorizationRuleName.Length < 1)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.MinLength, "authorizationRuleName", 1);
                }
            }
            if (parameters == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "parameters");
            }
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                parameters.Validate();
            }
            if (Client.ApiVersion == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "this.Client.ApiVersion");
            }
            if (Client.SubscriptionId == null)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(ValidationRules.CannotBeNull, "this.Client.SubscriptionId");
            }
            // Tracing
            bool _shouldTrace = ServiceClientTracing.IsEnabled;
            string _invocationId = null;
            if (_shouldTrace)
            {
                _invocationId = ServiceClientTracing.NextInvocationId.ToString();
                Dictionary<string, object> tracingParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                tracingParameters.Add("resourceGroupName", resourceGroupName);
                tracingParameters.Add("namespaceName", namespaceName);
                tracingParameters.Add("authorizationRuleName", authorizationRuleName);
                tracingParameters.Add("parameters", parameters);
                tracingParameters.Add("cancellationToken", cancellationToken);
                ServiceClientTracing.Enter(_invocationId, this, "RegenerateKeys", tracingParameters);
            }
            // Construct URL
            var _baseUrl = Client.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri;
            var _url = new System.Uri(new System.Uri(_baseUrl + (_baseUrl.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/")), "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}/AuthorizationRules/{authorizationRuleName}/regenerateKeys").ToString();
            _url = _url.Replace("{resourceGroupName}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceGroupName));
            _url = _url.Replace("{namespaceName}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(namespaceName));
            _url = _url.Replace("{authorizationRuleName}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(authorizationRuleName));
            _url = _url.Replace("{subscriptionId}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Client.SubscriptionId));
            List<string> _queryParameters = new List<string>();
            if (Client.ApiVersion != null)
            {
                _queryParameters.Add(string.Format("api-version={0}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Client.ApiVersion)));
            }
            if (_queryParameters.Count > 0)
            {
                _url += (_url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + string.Join("&", _queryParameters);
            }
            // Create HTTP transport objects
            var _httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();
            HttpResponseMessage _httpResponse = null;
            _httpRequest.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
            _httpRequest.RequestUri = new System.Uri(_url);
            // Set Headers
            if (Client.GenerateClientRequestId != null && Client.GenerateClientRequestId.Value)
            {
                _httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-ms-client-request-id", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
            if (Client.AcceptLanguage != null)
            {
                if (_httpRequest.Headers.Contains("accept-language"))
                {
                    _httpRequest.Headers.Remove("accept-language");
                }
                _httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-language", Client.AcceptLanguage);
            }


            if (customHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach(var _header in customHeaders)
                {
                    if (_httpRequest.Headers.Contains(_header.Key))
                    {
                        _httpRequest.Headers.Remove(_header.Key);
                    }
                    _httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(_header.Key, _header.Value);
                }
            }

            // Serialize Request
            string _requestContent = null;
            if(parameters != null)
            {
                _requestContent = Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Client.SerializationSettings);
                _httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(_requestContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                _httpRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType =System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            }
            // Set Credentials
            if (Client.Credentials != null)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Client.Credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(_httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            // Send Request
            if (_shouldTrace)
            {
                ServiceClientTracing.SendRequest(_invocationId, _httpRequest);
            }
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            _httpResponse = await Client.HttpClient.SendAsync(_httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (_shouldTrace)
            {
                ServiceClientTracing.ReceiveResponse(_invocationId, _httpResponse);
            }
            HttpStatusCode _statusCode = _httpResponse.StatusCode;
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            string _responseContent = null;
            if ((int)_statusCode != 200)
            {
                var ex = new ErrorResponseException(string.Format("Operation returned an invalid status code '{0}'", _statusCode));
                try
                {
                    _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    ErrorResponse _errorBody =  Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(_responseContent, Client.DeserializationSettings);
                    if (_errorBody != null)
                    {
                        ex.Body = _errorBody;
                    }
                }
                catch (JsonException)
                {
                    // Ignore the exception
                }
                ex.Request = new HttpRequestMessageWrapper(_httpRequest, _requestContent);
                ex.Response = new HttpResponseMessageWrapper(_httpResponse, _responseContent);
                if (_shouldTrace)
                {
                    ServiceClientTracing.Error(_invocationId, ex);
                }
                _httpRequest.Dispose();
                if (_httpResponse != null)
                {
                    _httpResponse.Dispose();
                }
                throw ex;
            }
            // Create Result
            var _result = new AzureOperationResponse<AccessKeys>();
            _result.Request = _httpRequest;
            _result.Response = _httpResponse;
            if (_httpResponse.Headers.Contains("x-ms-request-id"))
            {
                _result.RequestId = _httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-request-id").FirstOrDefault();
            }
            // Deserialize Response
            if ((int)_statusCode == 200)
            {
                _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    _result.Body = Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessKeys>(_responseContent, Client.DeserializationSettings);
                }
                catch (JsonException ex)
                {
                    _httpRequest.Dispose();
                    if (_httpResponse != null)
                    {
                        _httpResponse.Dispose();
                    }
                    throw new SerializationException("Unable to deserialize the response.", _responseContent, ex);
                }
            }
            if (_shouldTrace)
            {
                ServiceClientTracing.Exit(_invocationId, _result);
            }
            return _result;
        }
```

Hope it helps.

**MV**